# Watcher not firing

Tags: vuejs2, vue-chartjs, bryntum-grid

I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong. Watcher not firing when childProps is changed. I look at Vue devtools show that object is changing. But when I do a console.log it doesn't show that it's hitting my watcher. I have a table library that I'm using called bryntum-grid, that when I click on a row I get the id for that row. I'm getting the id in the child, but can't get the watcher to console.log the val when clicked.

```html
<template>
  <div class="dashboard-widget-wrapper">
    <h5 class="fw-normal dashboard-table-title">Review Items By Entitlement Type</h5>
    <div>
      <Doughnut
        v-if="loaded"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :data="chartData"
        :plugins="plugins"
        v-model="childProps"
      >
      </Doughnut>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'WidgetReviewItemsByEntitlementType',
  props: ['childProps'],
  components: {
    Doughnut
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      data: '',
      id: null,
      chartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: ['#5acbe9', '#fabf3f', '#f67599', '#3898ff', '#fcafc1'],
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        layout: {
          padding: 20
        },
        plugins: {
          title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Current Number of Alerts by Type'
          },
          customCanvasBackgroundColor: {
            color:
              document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-theme') === 'dark'
                ? '#44444a'
                : 'white'
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              color:
                document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-theme') === 'dark'
                  ? '#c0c1c2'
                  : '#606263'
            }
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      },
      plugins: [
        {
          id: 'customCanvasBackgroundColor',
          beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
            const { ctx } = chart
            ctx.save()
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'
            ctx.fillStyle = options.color || '#99ffff'
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height)
            ctx.restore()
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getAlertsByType() {
      axios
        .get('/widgets/test/' + this.id)
        .then(response => {
          this.chartData.datasets[0].data = response.data.data
          this.chartData.labels = response.data.labels
          this.loaded = true
        })
        .catch(error => {
          //console.log(error);
        })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getAlertsByType()
  },
  watch: {
    childProps: function (val) {
      console.log(val)
      this.id = val
      this.getAlertsByType()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can't put props into v-model as they are read-only. Maybe try replacing the v-model on the Doughnut with update events

Comment: A watcher on a prop always fires when the prop's value has changed in the parent component, regardless of how the prop is consumed in the child component. You cannot receive a useful answer until you show where and how you are changing the value of `childProps` and how you're passing it to the child component. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or a similar service.